# how to separate multiple values which has single key in Property files in Mule

Tags: mule

Here is an Example which is to be place in a property file and should get separated otherwise it read it as single string.

Trade&Credit= getTrade&Credit;addTrade&Credit;findTrade&Credit;updateTrade&Credit;addTrade&CreditContact;updateTrade&CreditContact;

Answer (score 1):

To access a property from property file in groovy component, you can use the following.

```
System.getProperty("propertyKey")
```

Another way round is, assuming you store the value from the property file in a flow variable named property file, splitting in for each. Just place the below expression in for each, and it will split the value as per separator.

```
#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(flowVars.propertyValue, ';')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer and groovy component to do this. See the below example

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will use the groovy component.
But i am trying to separate it in Property files where it consists of all key value pair, i made several property placeholders there how will the separate it.
Please help me with this.